# Dynamically create an inner class in a class in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

To automate a Django API I'd like to dynamically generate ModelSerializer classes, such as:

```
class AppleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Apple
        fields = '__all__'

class BananaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Banana
        fields = '__all__'
```

Creating a regular class is fairly simple (see below). How do you dynamically create the inner Meta class as well??

```
for serialmodel in ['Apple', 'Banaba']:
        class_name = serialmodel + 'Serializer'
        globals()[class_name] = type(class_name, (serializers.ModelSerializer,), {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
for serialmodel in ['Apple', 'Banana']:
        class_name = serialmodel + 'Serializer'
        Meta = type('Meta', (object, ), {'model': globals()[serialmodel], 'fields': '__all__'})
        globals()[class_name] = type(class_name, (serializers.ModelSerializer,), {'Meta':Meta, })
```

Very useful if you have a lot of generic models in Django :)

Or, when you want to do this for all models automatically:

```
models = dict(apps.all_models['your_django_app'])
for name, model in models.items():
    class_name = name[:1].upper() + name[1:] + 'Serializer'
    Meta = type('Meta', (object, ), {'model': model, 'fields': '__all__'})
    globals()[class_name] = type(class_name, (serializers.ModelSerializer,), {'Meta':Meta, })
```

Comment: It does not work. `type('Meta', (object, ), {'model': model, 'fields': '__all__'})` fails with error: `KeyError: '__module__'`